# api.add_files is missing a file in Meteor package

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm adding three files for the client in my Meteor package like so:

```
api.add_files([
  'lib/client/newsletter_banner.html',
  'lib/client/newsletter_banner.css',
  'lib/client/templates.js'
  ], ['client']);
```

`newsletter_banner.html` defines a template which is not available when I load the site. If I look through the sources in Devtools, I can see that the CSS and JS files are available, but the HTML file is not. Why is this? I've confirmed that the filename is correct and even changed it thinking that name might be unavailable to me for whatever reason, but the file is still not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html files are loaded by the `templating` package, so you need to add it to your package as well:

```
  api.use(['templating', 'spacebars', 'ui'], 'client');
```

Comment: That made the HTML available. Thank you! I still have a problem with the template, though. I may need to make a new question, but I'll run it by you. It's still saying the template is undefined. I can look at the generated JS and see that the template is defined before I override the default template with it although this is where I'm getting the undefined error. Any ideas?

Comment: Include "spacebars" and "ui" packages just to be sure – I've tweaked the code in the answer. Did this help?

Comment: That didn't seem to help. The template is still not defined according to Devtools.